# Find the best unbiased estimator for $\mu^T \mu + 1^T \mu$.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ independent $n$-dimensional vectors with the same distribution $N(\mu, I)$. Find the best unbiased estimator for

$$
\mu^T \mu + 1^T\mu
$$

where $1^T = (1, 1, \dots, 1)$.

How to solve this problem?

Thx.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i want to take that MLE of $\mu^T \mu$ is $\bar{X}^T \bar{X}$.

$$
E(\bar{X}^T \bar{X}) = \frac{1}{n} I + \mu^T\mu
$$

But i don't know how to solve another part for $1^T\mu$.

Comment: What is $\bar X$?

Comment: $ \bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

Comment: Yes, it should be vector. So what would be the best MLE of $\mu$?

Answer (score 0):

As the joint pdf of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a member of a regular (full rank) exponential family, it follows that a complete sufficient sufficient statistic for $\mu$ is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$, or equivalently the sample mean vector $\overline X=\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$. By Lehmann-Scheffé, the uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator of $g(\mu)=\mu^T\mu+1^T\mu$ is that unbiased estimator of $g$ which is based on $\overline X$.

Since $X_i\sim N_n(\mu,I_n)$ independently for all $i$, we have  $$\overline X=(\overline X_1,\ldots,\overline X_n)^T\sim N_n\left(\mu,\frac1n I_n\right)$$

So for every $\mu=(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)^T\in \mathbb R^n$,

$$E_{\mu}\left[\overline X^T\overline X\right]=E_{\mu}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \overline X_i^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac1n+\mu_i^2\right)=1+\mu^T\mu$$

And  $$E_{\mu}\left[1^T \overline X\right]=1^T\mu$$

Hence, $$E_{\mu}\left[\overline X^T\overline X+1^T\overline X-1\right]=g(\mu)$$